# thegraph.com How to update data source programmatically to track new contract?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, subgraph, thegraph.com, thegraph

Based on the [doc](https://thegraph.com/docs/define-a-subgraph#create-a-subgraph-project), it seems that we need to specify the address of the contract we want to track. How could I track the new contract? eg. After deploying a factory contract, we also need to track all the new contract created by the factory.

Understanding that you could do this manually or writing a Cron task to check new contract deployment and script a re-deployment, is there any way to do this programmatically within thegraph.com? eg. How does uniswap track new trading pair after someone adding them (new contract address to track I suppose)?

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.0;

interface IUniswapV2Factory {
  event PairCreated(address indexed token0, address indexed token1, address pair, uint);

  function getPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external view returns (address pair);
  function allPairs(uint) external view returns (address pair);
  function allPairsLength() external view returns (uint);

  function feeTo() external view returns (address);
  function feeToSetter() external view returns (address);

  function createPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external returns (address pair);
}
```

It's straight forward to track the factory contract. But after `createPair`, how could I track the newly created contract `address pair`? Is it possible to do this within thegraph.com? Or do I have to do it the hard way?

Answer:  https://thegraph.com/docs/define-a-subgraph#data-source-templates

Answer (score 1):

Usually, factory contract emits an event when it deploys a new contract. Just track this event. However the question lacks the source code of the contracts so it is hard to say.

Comment: thanks for your reply. `event PairCreated(address indexed token0, address indexed token1, address pair, uint);` How do you start to track the newly deployed contract `address pair` ?

Comment: The contract is in `address pair` AFK

Comment: @noooooooob did you figure out the answer? looking to do something similar

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `dataSources` dynamically. You must create a `templates` on your `subgraph.yaml` file for the child contract. If you checked the Uniswap subgraph, the factory contract is a [dataSources](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-subgraph/blob/master/subgraph.yaml#L6), but the `Pair` (the child contract) used [templates](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-subgraph/blob/master/subgraph.yaml#L34).

It is explained in [the graph documentation](https://thegraph.com/docs/en/developing/creating-a-subgraph/#data-source-templates-for-dynamically-created-contracts).

Answer (score 0):

you can look into the official doc of subgraph. https://thegraph.com/docs/en/developing/creating-a-subgraph/#data-source-templates